# Evaluating a right-continuous step function in an efficient way

Tags: stata

Suppose I have a right-continuous step (or staircase) function `s` which jumps at the time points contained in a variable `t`: e.g. `s` could be the Kaplan-Meier estimator of time-to-event data obtained by `sts gen`.

Now, suppose I am given another variable `r` also containing time points that are possibly different from those contained in `t` and that I want to create another variable `p` which is my step function evaluated at the time points in `r`.

```
 t  |  s   |  r
0.5 | 0.9  | 0.7  
1.2 | 0.85 | 0.8
1.5 | 0.8  | 1.25
1.5 | 0.8  | 1.3
```

My data could look something like what is shown above, and in this situation we would have

```
 p 
0.9
0.9
0.85
0.85
```

or in other words for each value of `r` we find the largest `t` value that is smaller than or equal to `r` and put `p` equal to `s`.

My question is: how do I do this in an efficient way? Obviously, I can, for every `r`-value, do the following:

```
gen diff=(r-t) if(r>=t)
sort diff
sum s if(_n==1)
```

but this is not what I'm looking for since this is very time-consuming when the number of observations are large.

Comment: Orthogonal to the question but `di s[1]` is more direct and efficient as a way to see the first value than `sum s if _n == 1` after sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you think of your problem slightly differently, namely that you have new values of `t` for which `s` is not known; your interpolation rule is to replace by the previous known value of `s`. The procedure in Stata terms is written up in [this Stata FAQ](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/replacing-missing-values/).

```
. list, sep(0)

     +------------+
     |    t     s |
     |------------|
  1. |   .5    .9 |
  2. |  1.2   .85 |
  3. |  1.5    .8 |
  4. |  1.5    .8 |
  5. |   .7     . |
  6. |   .8     . |
  7. | 1.25     . |
  8. |  1.3     . |
     +------------+

 . sort t s

 . replace s = s[_n-1] if missing(s)
 (4 real changes made)

 . list, sep(0)

     +------------+
     |    t     s |
     |------------|
  1. |   .5    .9 |
  2. |   .7    .9 |
  3. |   .8    .9 |
  4. |  1.2   .85 |
  5. | 1.25   .85 |
  6. |  1.3   .85 |
  7. |  1.5    .8 |
  8. |  1.5    .8 |
     +------------+
```

Note: `sort`ing on `t` then `s` allows known `s` values to be copied for the same `t`.

Comment: Wow, that was neat. Thank you very much for a quick and useful answer.